# How do I burn .img files onto floppy disk?

Tags: windows-xp, images, floppy

I want to "burn" 3 DOS 6.22 floppy disks. I have 3 .img files but I can't "burn" these .img files onto a floppy. I get the message that the file is too big for the target.

What tool can I use (I used one in the past but I don't remember which one...) to "burn" .img file to the floppy disk?

Comment: Clearly you know that you don’t “burn” a floppy; you *write* it. `;-)`

Comment: Yhea, write is now a bit old as word ;)

Comment: Not really, you *write* to hard-drives, to flash-drives, to memory-cards, files, CMOS, EEPROMs… (Only optical discs and flash EPROMs are burned. I can’t really think of other types of / verbs for data writing. Huh.)

Comment: Well.. I'm a french canadian so we don't often use the word Write. It's burn or copy. Pretty much...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For floppy disks, It isn't free but I would highly recommend [Winimage](http://www.winimage.com/), I recently used this when messing around with PXE disk images and it works very well for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 12):

And just for completion - `dd`, the usual Linux way. (You didn't mention your OS.)

```
dd if=disk1.img of=/dev/fd0
```

---

[On Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd):

```
dd if=disk1.img of=\\?\Device\Floppy0
```

Comment: Yhea sorry, I wanted to burn .img file over a Windows XP Pro SP3 OS. Sorry for the lack of info.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably remembering `rawrite.exe`; it used to be included with early Linux distributions like Slackware for creating a bootable LILO floppy.  [Find it here.](http://www.fdos.org/ripcord/rawrite/)  ([Author's site](http://uranus.it.swin.edu.au/~jn/linux/rawwrite.htm), may be down.)

Comment: ahh, if only we could tag answers too.  this one so needs a **[nostalgia]** tag.

Comment: I'm not against the idea! For old old old technologies

Answer (score 6):

I used to use [RawWrite for Windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/rawwrite).  Works quite nicely and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

I'm still using floppy disks (I'm very nostalgic to these days of the 90's) and I recommend [DiskWRITE](http://freeextractor.sourceforge.net/diskwrite/) for those who use Windows.

Alternatively, if you're using Linux,nothing is like using `dd`:

```
dd if=imagename.img of=/dev/fd0 bs=1024 conv=sync;sync
```

(I took this from the [DEBIAN documentation](http://www.debian.org/releases//lenny/powerpc/ch04s03.html.en))

Comment: For some reason this program do not work with all .IMG files